# Button in collection view (UPCarouselFlowLayout) does not receive onclick event

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carousel

I have created a carousel view using `UPCarouselFlowLayout` and it works well. But when the `UIButton` in the view is clicked, no action occurs. How do I make it so that when the `UIButton` is clicked, it calls a particular action?

**CollectionViewCell**:

```
class MagicCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var magicview: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var magicimage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var magiclabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var magicbutton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.magicview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        // Initialization code

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.magicview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            self.magicview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            self.magicview.layer.shadowOpacity = 10.0
            self.magicview.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
            self.magicview.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.magicview.bounds).cgPath
            self.magicview.layer.shouldRasterize = false


        }
    }    
}
```

**Magic1.swift**

```
import UPCarouselFlowLayout

class Magic1: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var magiccollection: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        magiccollection.register(UINib.init(nibName: "MagicCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "magiccidentifier")

        let floawLayout = UPCarouselFlowLayout()
        floawLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60.0, height: magiccollection.frame.size.height)
        floawLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        floawLayout.sideItemScale = 0.8
        floawLayout.sideItemAlpha = 1.0
        floawLayout.spacingMode = .fixed(spacing: 5.0)
        magiccollection.collectionViewLayout = floawLayout

        magiccollection.delegate = self
        magiccollection.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = sexeducollec.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "magiccidentifier", for: indexPath) as!MagicCollectionViewCell

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            cell.magiclabel.text = "Tester title"
            cell.sexedimage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "merlin")

        }else if indexPath.row == 1{
            cell.magiclabel.text = "love is in the air"

        }else{
            cell.magiclabel.text = "Title - \(indexPath.row + 1)"

        }

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0{
        print("Accio")

        }else if indexPath.row == 1{
            print("alohamora")

        }
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is when `magicbutton` is clicked at `indexPath.row == 0` it calls a specific action and when it is clicked at `indexPath.row == 1` it calls a specific function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach! Also, You can call closure at IBAction

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

      override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return 2
      }

       override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
         if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "magiccidentifier", for: indexPath) as? MagicCollectionViewCell {
             switch indexPath.row {
             case 0:
                 cell.onCellTouched = { print("Hi")}
             default:
                 cell.onCellTouched = { print("By") }
             }
             return cell
         }

         return UICollectionViewCell()
     }

     override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let item = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MagicCollectionViewCell
         item?.onCellTouched()
     }
 }

class MagicCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     var onCellTouched: () -> Void = { assertionFailure("Cell action didn't set up") }

     override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()

         self.backgroundColor = .black
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `IBAction` of your button in `MagicCollectionViewCell`. So add an action for your button:

```
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```